# jsonObject as string - searching for regular expression to remove password field

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a json String which will have somewhere in its content a string like this:

```
 "password": "password2"
```

This can be anywhere in the json string, so don't assume it's on the first level. it can even be in a jsonArray. So I need to search the entire string and remove this field, or put its value as null.

So I need to be able to search the entire string and replace the password.  For example the string could look like this:

I just want it for logging. My issue is, I want to remove the password value as I am sharing it with a 3rd party.

I need in java to use a regular expression that will search this string and replace the password value with an empty string, or I can do md5 of password even.  It must not fail if there is no password string existing.  How can I do this?   So to be clear, given any input as a string I want the result after filter to be:

```
 "password": ""
```

Or it can be a md5 of password value instead of null if its easier. Can you help?

So the function I want to create will look like this:

```
public String removePasswordFromJsonString(String jsonString){


  //.. do the regualar expression work here....

  return jsonString;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public String removePasswordFromJsonString(String jsonString){

  // Handle null input
  if (jsonString == null) {
    return null;
  }

  // Replace all password values with empty strings
  return jsonString.replaceAll(
      "(\\n?\\s*\"password\"\\s?:\\s?\")[^\\n\"]*(\",?\\n?)", "$1$2");

}
```

This should be able to replace all occurrences of a password's value with an empty string, regardless of how deeply nested it is.

**EDIT:** This will handle zero or one spaces on each side of the colon (`:`).  To handle any number of spaces, use an asterisk (`*`) instead of a question mark (`?`):

`"(\\n?\\s*\"password\"\\s*:\\s*\")[^\\n\"]*(\",?\\n?)"`

Comment: I see the problem... I assumed spaces between the key and the ":" and the value.  I made the spaces optional.  Try it again.

Comment: That worked. do you think it will work if there is  spaces though ? isn't there a way to say for "any number of spaces". and what does the $1$2 mean

Comment: It will work for zero or one spaces.  That's what the ```?``` mark does in this part: ```\\s?:\\s?```  If you want it to do *any* number of spaces, then use ```*``` instead of ```?```, so it would be ```\\s*:\\s*```.  Updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this ,

```
String response="{ \"password\": \"password2\", \"otherValue\": \"c18bd5a4-f734-44bf-be77-56b1267dcb9e\" }";
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
    jsonObject.put("password", "");
    System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output :

```
{"password":"","otherValue":"c18bd5a4-f734-44bf-be77-56b1267dcb9e"}
```

**Note :** the above code will set your password field empty , no matter where is it , sequence doesn't matter , it will just overwrite that field with empty string

---

If you still like to use `regex` then apply this

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SwYghc/1)

```
    String response="{\n \"email_address\": \"user_JeAw@domain.com\",\n \"password\": \"password1\",\n \"device_id\": \"wtnmrrwyhjeatdcnt\",\n \"device_name\": \"xshjavwuqmtnkhuuxkjfgsnfnd\",\n \"device_token\": \"03118557-2755-495b-f97e\"\n}";
    try {
        
        String newstr= response.replaceAll("(?:\\bpassword)\\W+\\w+", "password\":\"");
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(newstr);
        if (jsonObject.getString("password").isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("empty password" + jsonObject.getString("password"));
        }           
    } catch (JSONException e) {     }
```

Output:

```
empty password
```

`(?:\\bpassword)\\W+\\w+`

`(?:\\bpassword)` match `password` string

- `?:` to match the token
- `\\b` boundary mean don't match something like `another_password`

`\\W+` match any non-word character mean special characters like `,\n`

`\w+` capture one or more words , to capture string after `\":"`  etc

Comment: i updated my question. it has to be for any json structure . so the field can be very deep inside json. can you help

Comment: @j2emanue read the Note section of my post , this will only fail when you have nested json response mean object inside object so can you confirm

Comment: the regular expression did not work. when i tried removePassword("{\n  \"email_address\": \"user_JeAw@domain.com\",\n  \"password\": \"password1\",\n  \"device_id\": \"wtnmrrwyhjeatdcnt\",\n  \"device_name\": \"xshjavwuqmtnkhuuxkjfgsnfnd\",\n  \"device_token\": \"03118557-2755-495b-f97e\"\n}")

Comment: @j2emanue you didn't mention there will be \n the even not suppose to be there in json format , doesn't look like a right format , you created if yourself ?

Comment: oh your right. yah i was escaping it on line.  sorry ..let me try again.

Comment: @j2emanue i tested this with your latest input and it is working no issue , let me know if there is any

Answer (score 3):

Temporarily remove the password from the object while you convert it to a JSON string.

I don't know the exact Java code, but here is pseudo-code:

```
tempPass = jsonObject.password;
jsonObject.password = "";
jsonString = jsonObject.toString();
jsonObject.password = tempPass;
```

If you know that the password will never contain a double quote (a dangerous assumption in general), you could use the regular expression `"password":\s*".*?"` and replace it with `"password": ""`.

```
String regex = "\"password\":\\s*\".*?\"";
```

Comment: i cant do it like that. i am not sure what the json structure will be. it will be given to me entirely as a string first.

Comment: it should be `jsonObject.put("password","");`

Comment: Trying to parse JSON with a regular expression is not easy, there are many special cases you have to handle, such as escaped characters in the value.

Comment: @j2emanue Maybe you can parse the JSON back into an object, then look through it recursively, looking for elements named `password` and removing them.

Comment: i didn't notice the `pseudo-code:` text  , rightfully +1

Comment: @PavneetSingh I added it after your comment. :)

Comment: @BArmar i am having trouble escaping the regular expression you gave for some reason. i am trying to store it in a variable like this String REGEX="password":\s*".*?"

Comment: I'm not a Java programmer, but I assume you need to escape quotes that are inside quotes: `String regex = "\"password\":\\s*\".*?\"";`

Answer (score 1):

Using this expression

```
"([a-zA-Z]*(pass|secure)[a-zA-Z]*)":"([^"]+)"
```

Remove value in sensitive field such as *pass* or *secure*

```
        public static string HideSensitiveDatastring jsonString)
        {
            var senitivePatterns 
                = "\"([a-zA-Z]*(pass|secure)[a-zA-Z]*)\":\"([^\"]+)\"";
            return Regex.Replace(jsonString, senitivePatterns, "\"$1\":\"***\"",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        }
```

[Demo https://coding.tools/regex-replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfp51.png)